# Parse through Each li tag in browser using 'WatiN'

Tags: c#, watin

I am using a watin dll to browse through a webpage, click on a link in `li` tag, go to the next page, fetch some data, go back to previous page and click the link in the next `li` tag.

I am able to do this with one link in `li` tag. I want to get all the `li` tag under`ul <classname>` click on each link and perform the above procedure. How can I get all the `li` and loop through each page?

HTML code of the page is like this:

```
<ul id="ul_classname" class="search-result-set">
    <li class="">
        <div class="Div_Classname">
            <h3 class="standard_font">
                <a class="a class_name" href="link to be clicked">text to be displayed</a>
            </h3>
            <p class="word-wrap"></p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <div class="Div_Classname">
            <h3 class="standard_font">
                <a class="a class_name" href="link to be clicked">text to be displayed</a>
            </h3>
            <p class="word-wrap"></p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTH!

```
private void CrawlSite()
{
    int idx = 0;
    do
    {
        idx = this.ClickLink(idx);
    }
    while (idx != -1);
}

private int ClickLink(int idx)
{
    WatiN.Core.Browser browser = GetBrowser();

    ListItemCollection listItems = browser.List("ul_classname").ListItems;
    if (idx > listItems.Count - 1)
        return -1;

    Link lnk = listItems[idx].Link(Find.ByClass("a class_name"));
    lnk.Click();

    //TODO: get your data

    browser.Back();

    return idx + 1;
}
```

Comment: Its working fine if i open the new browser every time. If i am using the same browser it gives me error when the link gets clicked Error-"function evaluation timed out" at class_name. Do you know what is the cause regarding this

Comment: Are you using the watin page model?  If so, you may have to re-grab your list page each time before you interrogate it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this code (Linq to XML)

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(yourFile);

var terms= from term in xdoc.Descendants("ul")
        select new
        {
              Class= term.Attribute("class").Value
        };

foreach(var li in terms)
{
   Console.Write(li.Class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
LinkCollection links = ie.Links;
foreach (var link in links)
{
    link.Click();
    // Do something
    ie.Back();
}
```